# Why is the service FirebaseInstanceIdService lost in the firebase new updates?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

The problem is, I wanted to use Firebase cloud messaging in my chat app. Implementing the firebase documents in my android studio, I need to create a class which extends the  `FirebaseInstanceIdService`. However, this service seems missing.

```
 public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends  FirebaseInstanceIdService{
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `FirebaseInstanceIdService` is deprecated in the new version. Now you can get the updated token in **MyFirebaseMessagingService**.

In `MyFirebaseMessagingService` new method is introduced for the updated token if in case it expired.

```
override fun onNewToken(token: String?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: $token")

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(token)
}
```

For the more details please visit [fcm](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks